# Why is my css file displaying as output?

Tags: html, css, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have converted a web application over to spring boot mostly successfully. The only issue I have encountered is that after login (using spring security) I am supposed to be redirected to a page that contains a link to a local version of a font-awesome.css. However, the first time I login the css file is displayed rather than the actual html page. If I step back and then step forward, the page is properly displayed from then on. My question is what could possibly be causing this behavior?

Here is the link to the css from the html page (which is in the head section):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/font-awesome.css" th:href="@{/css/font-awesome.css}"></link>
```

I also tested by removing the 'th:href...' attribute but the behavior persists.

Comment: Could you share a sample project on GitHub that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Absoultely, here is my project on github: (https://github.com/dirkwiggley/gameserver). The html file where the issue occurs is src/main/resources/shared/selectCampaign.html